# getItemViewType() for two list in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement two different list views along with other items in a single recyclerview.

The getItemViewType() for the adapter is:

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(isPositionTitle(position))
            return TYPE_TITLE;
        if(isPositionTitleList(position))
            return TYPE_TITLE_ITEM;
        if(isPositionAdd(position))
            return TYPE_TITLE_ADD;
        if(isPositionSeperator(position))
            return TYPE_SEPERATOR;
        if(isPositionTicked(position))
            return TYPE_TICKED;
        if(isPositionTickedList(position))
            return TYPE_TICKED_LIST;

        return 0;
    }


private boolean isPositionTitle(int position)
{
    return position == 0;
}

private boolean isPositionTitleList(int position)
{
    return position == 1;
}

private boolean isPositionAdd(int position)
{
    return position == 2;
}

private boolean isPositionSeperator(int position)
{
    return position == 3;
}

private boolean isPositionTicked(int position)
{
    return position == 4;
}

private boolean isPositionTickedList(int position)
{
    return position == 5;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tickedList.size()+titleList.size()+4;
}
```

The problem is that only the **first listitem** is shown in both the lists. What should be done to  show all the items in both the listviews?

Code for recyclerview setup:

```
 rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.act1_recycler);

MyLinearLayoutManager llm = new MyLinearLayoutManager(this.getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);

rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

adapter = new Activity8Adapter(getApplicationContext(),titleList,tickedList);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Please post your code where you setup your RecyclerView.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: You need to check if the current position is within the bounds of your lists in `isPositionTitleList()` and `isPositionTickedList()`. As you do it currently, itemViewType TYPE_TITLE_ITEM and TYPE_TICKED_LIST are only returned for a single entry, while all the rest (position > 5) will be of itemViewType 0.

Comment: silly me.that was quite trivial. thanks.